# problem with redirect ´stdout´ to a file and ´exit´ command

Tags: c, linux, shell

The following program implements a shell (simplified). I have a problem: when I redirect `stdout` to a file, the`$`symbols appear at the end of the file. What edits do I need to do to stop appearing?

I also have a problem running the `exit` command: it does not exit the program. How can I solve it?
The shell reads the commands and tries to execute them.

code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *
getinput(char *buffer, size_t buflen) {
    printf("$$ ");
    return fgets(buffer, buflen, stdin);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    while (getinput(buf, sizeof(buf))) {
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';

        if((pid=fork()) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: can't fork: %s\n",
                    strerror(errno));
            continue;
        } else if (pid == 0) {   /* child */
            execlp(buf, buf, (char *)0);
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: couldn't exec %s: %s\n", buf,
                    strerror(errno));
            exit(EX_UNAVAILABLE);
        }

        /* parent waits */
        if ((pid=waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: waitpid error: %s\n",
                    strerror(errno));
        }
    }

    exit(EX_OK);
}
```

I also have a problem running the `exit` command: it does not exit the program. How can I solve it?

the terminal looks like this:

```
mike@ubuntu:~process/homework$ echo "foobar" > input
mike@ubuntu:~process/homework$ cat output`
$$ $$ $$ mike@ubuntu:~process/homework$ ./shell < input > output 2 > err
mike@ubuntu:~process/homework$ cat output
$$ $$ $$ mike@ubuntu:~process/homework$ cat err
shell: couldn't exec foobar: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Exit must be a built-in executed without forking.

Comment: If you don't use `argc` and `argv` (at the moment) then define `int main(void) { … }`.

Comment: You don't show any parsing or I/O redirection code.  We can't help you resolve the problems in code you don't show.

Comment: If you mean that when you run `myshell >output` the prompts appear in output, that is inevitable given your code.  Maybe you should be testing whether the output is a terminal and only write prompts if it is.  Or maybe you should be testing whether the input is a terminal — you don't want prompts to appear if the script comes from a file.  Maybe you write to the terminal (`/dev/tty`) if you write prompts at all.  It requires some thought and care.

Comment: i update the question

Comment: Your update shows that you're providing your shell's input from a file via the system shell's input redirection, and that you're sending your shell's output to a file via the system shell's output redirection.  When neither standard input nor standard output is a terminal, your shell should not emit prompts.  Your `getinput()` function writes the prompt to standard output unconditionally.  The [`isatty()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) function should be a help here.  This is what I discussed in my previous comment — you'll need to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` is a shell builtin, and should be handled before any forking occurs.

Use [`isatty(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to determine if `stdout` refers to a terminal, and only print your prompt if it does.

Here is a basic example, but do note that a real `exit` command supports a single numerical argument, which becomes the exit status of the shell, otherwise the exit status is that of the last command executed.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *
getinput(char *buffer, size_t buflen) {
    if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
        printf("$$ ");
    return fgets(buffer, buflen, stdin);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    pid_t pid;
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    while (getinput(buf, sizeof(buf))) {
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';

        if (0 == strcmp(buf, "exit"))
            exit(WEXITSTATUS(status));

        if((pid=fork()) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: can't fork: %s\n",
                    strerror(errno));
            continue;
        } else if (pid == 0) {   /* child */
            execlp(buf, buf, (char *)0);
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: couldn't exec %s: %s\n", buf,
                    strerror(errno));
            exit(EX_UNAVAILABLE);
        }

        /* parent waits */
        if ((pid=waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "shell: waitpid error: %s\n",
                    strerror(errno));
        }
    }

    exit(EX_OK);
}
```

Comment: There is no parsing code in the OP's code — no command can be given arguments yet.  That's a semi-legitimate design for a preliminary implementation of a shell.  You don't address the main question, though, about prompts appearing in the output file when the user's shell's output is sent to a file by the system shell's output redirection (though I grant you the context wasn't clear when you answered but clarifying the question is a good idea).